# Haskell indexing changes list in ghci

Tags: haskell

Day 1 of haskell.

I think what I am doing here is creating a list of Text (strings), then examining the first element.
What I actually seem to be doing is replacing my it variable with the first element of it.

Anyone explain?

```
Prelude T> it = T.splitOn " " "Will Gil"
it :: [T.Text]
Prelude T> it     
["Will","Gil"]
it :: [T.Text]
Prelude T> it !! 0
"Will"
it :: T.Text
Prelude T> it     
"Will"
it :: T.Text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`it` is a special variable in GHCi that have the last, non assigned, computed value.

So, when you give `it !! 0` the first time, GHCi will store its result into `it`, hence the result of the following time you give `it`.

It's terribly difficult for me to believe that you randomly chose a name for a variable (on your Day 1, by the way) and were so unlucky to pick `it` from within you head. I'm more inclined to think that you started studying/reading something about Haskell, and let it go to soon, played around in GHCi for 2 minutes max, and then asked a question here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But not for the pop psych